# How to use result again in this case

Tags: haskell, iteration

My task is:

> Implement the function `puzz`. It should simulate the game similar to 15 Puzzle. In our case, we have 25 squares, where 24 squares are occupied by tiles with big case letters from `'A'` to `'X'`. One tile is free and is denoted by `' '`. In each move, you can *move* a tile *(denoted by its letter)* into the free space. The function gets the original configuration and a sequence of *valid* moves. It should output the resulting configuration.

I am new to Haskell, I can only do one first move.

Result after the last move must be `["ABCDE", "FGHIJ", "KLMNO", "PQRST ", "UVWX_"]`. How to save the result of the first move and use it to do the second move, and the next, and then iterate some more?

```
s1 = ["AC DE",
      "FBHIJ",
      "KGLNO",
      "PQMRS",
      "UVWXT"]

p1 = "CBGLMRST"

puzz :: Result -> [Char] -> Result
puzz s1 p1 = 
   let i = 0
       p = p1 !! i
       change r = [ if c == ' ' then p else if c == p then ' ' else c | c <- r ]
       out = [ change r | r <- s1  ]
    in out
```

Comment: I tried a lot methods and adjustments, but without effect.

Comment: please explain what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Entry in s1 is like a puzzle array, in p1  moves to empty, After making movements we have  new puzzle array. First iterate ["A CDE","FBHIJ","KGLNO","PQMRS","UVWXT"]
result is  ["ABCDE", "FGHIJ", "KLMNO", "PQRST ", "UVWX "]

Comment: please explain what you are trying to achieve. give several minimal input-output pairs. in general, `foo f x = let {a = f x; b = f a; c = f b } in [x,a,b,c]` is one possibility. it is also equivalent to  `take 4 $ iterate f x`. or you can use recursion yourself: `bar f x = x : bar f (f x)`, using the result `(f x)` as input to the next recursive call to the same function `bar f`.

Comment: I understand what recursion is, but I can't use it. Can you please show how to use it in this case. I can't think as Haskellian yet.

Comment: when you say you can't use recursion, you mean it is forbidden by the task to use recursion? please clarify. (I've edited and voted to reopen).

Comment: I'm sorry, my English is poor. I meant that "I don't know how do it". Thank you for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The `s1` and the `p1` in the `puzz s1 p1` aren't your constants `s1` and `p1`. They are only templates. For example `puzz ["  B"] "B"` returns `["BB "]` and `p1` becomes `["  B"]` and `s1` becomes `"B"` in that function call.
2. Don't try iterate (I removed part of code with the `i`). Use recursion. There are no variables in Haskell, only constants and input parameters. Input parameter (represented by the template) should be in each call different (closer to the end) because of referential integrity.
3. Don't forget to finish the algorithm.

> `(p:p1)` - Template of input parameter which says that there is a nonempty list and the first character will be `p` and tail will be `p1`.
> `puzz s1 [] = s1` - When second parametr is empty list, then return first parameter (end).
> `puzz out p1` - Calling puzz for the changed `s1` as `out` and `p1` from `(p:p1)` (recursion).

```
s1 = ["AC DE","FBHIJ","KGLNO","PQMRS","UVWXT"]

p1 = "CBGLMRST"

puzz :: [String] -> [Char]-> [String]
puzz s1 (p:p1) =  let                  
                  change r = [ if c == ' ' then p else if c == p then ' ' else c | c <- r ]
                  out = [ change r | r <- s1  ]
                in puzz out p1
puzz s1 [] = s1
```

Output:

```
   puzz s1 p1
=> ["ABCDE","FGHIJ","KLMNO","PQRST","UVWX "]
```

Comment: Best thank you ! Yes, now I understand. Recursion applied to the result and the tail  of  control string in this case. It looks easy if you understand this. My way to Haskell is on the start. This is a really important step for me to understand, thank you.  Děkuji :-)